# How to record a video and sound in a avi file from the command line?

Tags: command-line, webcam, audio-recording, mencoder, video-recording

How can I record, in a single command both video from my webcam and sound from my microphone in a `.avi` file?

I tried below command:

```
streamer -q -c /dev/video0 -f rgb24 -r 3 -t 00:30:00 -o ~/outfile.avi
```

but it is not producing any sound.

Answer (score 1):

I finally end up with:

```
ffmpeg -f alsa -ac 2 -i plughw:0,0 -f video4linux2 -s vga -i /dev/video0 video.mp4
```

Comment: It looks like you may have two accounts by accident — you can [ask for them to be merged](/help/merging-accounts) if you like.